# Plugman: Is it possible to watch a local plugin and automatically install it in the Cordova project

Tags: cordova, plugins, plugman

I'm working on a Cordova plugin.

I have a local repo for my plugin, and each time I want to test my code, I have to uninstall the plugin, then reinstall it (and its dependencies), then build the project on my device.

It's kinda heavy.

Is that the official workflow ? Is there any watch system or something like "npm link" I could use ? Or should I simply create a symlink in my cordova project so it includes the local plugin ?

Thanks